# What is the label associated with AirBNB?

Tags: contract-law, residential-lease

How does one write no AirBNB into a rental contract that AirBNB or the like is forbidden?  Is this merely a form of subleasing?  Assume a venue of Florida.

Answer (score 1):

How about "no subletting" or "no short-term subletting" or "no short term rentals".  You can, of-course, make a term which mentions AirBNB specifically, but that may not yield the desired affect as there are other similar options.

Note that just putting something into a rental contract does not necessarily make it legal or otherwise, and the legality will depend on where you are.  In some places, forbidding AirBNB would be considered a breach of the right to quiet enjoyment, in others, having an AirBNB allowing AirBNB may incur additional council fees.

Comment: Is there an example where breach of right to quiet enjoyment includes subletting (AirBNB)?  Links in the above post would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: @gatorback - I have not been able to find a link to that, but my thinking is colored by the Melbourne Australian reporting on Owners Corporation 501391P v Balcombe.